# Find the maximum value of $x^2+12xy+2y^2$, among the points (x, y) for which $4x^2+y^2=25$ without using Lagrange multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, polar-coordinates

My attempt is the following.

> Using polar coordinates, let $(x, y) = (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$, where $$r^2 = \frac{\frac{25}{4}5}{25 \cos^2\theta+\frac{25}{4} \sin^2\theta}.$$
>   Then, the expression $x^2+12xy+2y^2$ becomes $r^2(\cos^2\theta+12 \cos\theta \sin\theta+2\sin^2\theta)$. It's a function of $\theta$, so find the derivative $f'$ of $f$, and then, let $f'$ equal $0$ to find the critical point.

But I get a really messy $f'$, and I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Probably a better substitution would be $(x,y) = \left( \frac{5}{2} \cos \theta, 5 \sin \theta \right)$. After that, before you differentiate try to bring the expression in the form of $\cos 2\theta$ and $\sin 2\theta$. That would make it much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that $(2x)^2 + y^2 = 4x^2 + y^2 = 25,$ we have that $2x = 5 \cos \theta$ and $y = 5 \sin \theta$ by the usual polar coordinates identifications. Consequently, we have that $$f(x, y) = x^2 + 12xy + 2y^2 = \frac{25}{4} \cos^2 \theta + 12 \cdot \frac{5}{2} \cos \theta \cdot 5 \sin \theta + 2 \cdot 25 \sin^2 \theta = g(\theta),$$ and we can use the Extreme Value Theorem to find the absolute maximum of $g(\theta)$ on the closed interval $[0, 2 \pi].$ Using the Product Rule and the Chain Rule, we have that $$g'(\theta) = -\frac{25}{2} \sin \theta \cos \theta - 150 \sin^2 \theta + 150 \cos^2 \theta + 100 \sin \theta \cos \theta = 150 u^2 + \frac{175}{2} uv - 150 v^2$$ by the substitution $u = \cos \theta$ and $v = \sin \theta.$ Observe that we have $g'(\theta) = 0$ if and only if $12 u^2 + 7uv - 12 v^2 = 0$ if and only if $(4u - 3v)(3u + 4v) = 0$ if and only if $\frac u v = \frac 3 4$ or $\frac u v = \frac{-4} 3$ if and only if $\cot \theta = \frac 3 4$ or $\cot \theta = \frac{-4} 3$ if and only if $\tan \theta = \frac 4 3$ or $\tan \theta = \frac{-3} 4.$

Can you finish the problem? (Use the Extreme Value Theorem on the following four points: the two critical points arising from $g'(\theta) = 0$ for $0 < \theta < 2 \pi$ and the two endpoints $\theta = 0$ and $\theta = 2 \pi.$)

Answer (score 1):

The extrema are reached with the two curves $f(x,y)=x^2+12xy+2y^2$ and $g(x,y)=4x^2+y^2$ tangential to each other, i.e. $\frac{f_x’ }{f_y’ }= \frac{g_x’ }{g_y’ } $, or

$$ \frac{x+6y}{6x+2y}= \frac{4x}y\implies (2y+3x)(3y-8x)=0$$

which leads to $y= -\frac32x,\> y= \frac83x$. Substitute them into $g(x,y)=25$ to get the tangential points $(\pm\frac32, \pm4)$ and $(\pm2, \mp3)$. Plug them into $f(x,y)$ to obtain

$$f_{max} = f( \pm\frac32, \pm4 ) =\frac{425}4 
, \>\>\>\>\> f_{min} = f( \pm2, \mp3) =-50$$

Comment: Thank, but why the extreme are reached if the two curves are tangential to each other?

Comment: @Cathy - note that the extrema are from the common points between the two curves. The tangential points are the extrema of the common points, which in most cases, including this one, correspond to the extreme values

Comment: I'm still confused, for example, $4x^2+y^2=25$ is a curve in the plane, but why $g(x,y)=4x^2+y^2$ is also a curve? And why two curves are tangential to each other, then $\frac{f_x’ }{f_y’ }= \frac{g_x’ }{g_y’ }$

Comment: @Cathy - $g(x,y)=k$ represents a family of ellipses, including $4x^2+y^2=25$. $ (f_x’,f_y’)$ is the normal vector of the curve $f(x,y)$ at point $(x,y)$ and at the tangential point, their normal vector coincide

Comment: Isn't that in fact the idea behind Lagrange multipliers?!